# IBM Mobilefirst Device Management Get Flag from MFP console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-console

IBM MobileFirst™ Platform Foundation maintains a database table of device IDs, among other device-related metadata, to enable this feature. In addition to the device ID column in the database, a status column is also kept. The possible status values are:

```
active
lost
stolen
expired 
disabled
```

After I enable the device management, I able to set the status to the respective device. If the device is marked as lost or stolen, can the device able to get the flag send from server and do some processing such as destroy JSON store when the device is online and the app is open? The server will return 404 or forbidden access, but the local JSONStore still consist of data. So we have to wipe off the local data too.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the full server response? Maybe we can start from there...

Comment: H Terry, is the JSONStore encrypted? If it is, then someone will not be able to open the JSONStore without the correct credentials.

Comment: Hi Chevy,
Sorry for late reply...Here is my response I get from server.
[TRACE] [WLNativeXHR] callback {"statusText":"Request failed: forbidden (403)","status":403,"headers":{"Pragma":"no-cache","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"119","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"WL-Authentication-Failure\":{\"wl_remoteDisableRealm\":{\"message\":\"This device has been decommissioned.\"}}}

Comment: Hi @DoraC ,
Yup, the JSON Store is encrypted. But data still remain in the lost device. Theoretically it should be safe, but there might have some security constraints from national central bank and client security and compliance.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at integrating with MaaS360. Specifically te Remote access control and wiping data section (link below). MaaS360 offers a simple integration for your IT admins to destroy all app data when a device is stolen or lost.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/integration-7-0/mobilefirst-protect/

Comment: Our client don't want to invest anymore in IBM Protect and want us to come out a turn around method to solve this issue.